# Plot polygons with different colors using rMaps

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to plot polygons on a map using rMaps and fill the polygons **with different colors**.

I tried unsuccessfully change the 'color' and 'fillcolor' attributes:

```
require(yaml)
library(rCharts)
library(rMaps)
library(plyr)

mk_polygon <- function(lats, lons, poly_color){ 
  stopifnot(length(lats)==length(lons))
  coord_list <- llply(seq_along(lats), function(i) c(lons[[i]], lats[[i]]))
  list(
    type = 'Feature',
    properties = list(color = poly_color,
                      fillcolor = poly_color,
                      name = "station"),
      geometry = list(type = 'Polygon',
                      coordinates = list(coord_list))
  )
}

style <- list()
polygons <- list()
path <- "C:/DataVisualization/polygons/"
files <- list.files(path)
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  poly <- read.csv(paste(path,files[i],sep=""),header=T)
  polygons[[length(polygons)+1]] <- mk_polygon(poly$lat, poly$lon, color[i])
}

NYC <- c(40.7142700, -74.0059700)

map <- Leaflet$new()
map$setView(NYC, zoom = 10)
map$geoJson(polygons)
map
```

My code plots all the polygons with the same color (blue, the default color).

Does anyone know how to change it?
Any help is greatly appreciated.